# import another jar's program into my jar

Tags: java, maven

I am super new to Java. I have a Java program which is deployed to a server as a .jar file. I have another executable program, also in Java, that I need it to call (in myjar.jar). At first I was basically shelling out and creating another java instance like:

```
List<String> commandAndParameters = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("java", "-jar", "myjar.jar"
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder();
builder.command(commandAndParameters);
Process process = builder.start();
...
```

This hasn't been working too well and it's also slow to launch a second instance of Java, so I thought I would just import the jar into my program and run the class directly. The main class is called Main and of course the method of the class that I would be calling is main. Which is a little weird, but I figured it could work (there's no rule saying you can't have another object with a main method, right?)

I'm not really sure how to import it though. I extracted myjar.jar to look at the structure and the class I want to use is at `a/b/c/Main.class`. The jar exists in the root directory of the program from which I'm trying to call it, so I naively tried import `a.b.c.Main` but of course that didn't work. I'm using IntelliJ and tried adding the .jar as a module (Project Structure->Modules->+->Import Module), I guess to add it to my classpath, but it just says "Cannot import anything from myjar.jar"

I'm using Maven for what it's worth. I need to get both IntelliJ working, and the jar produced by Maven working for when I build.

So clearly, I am super lost. I'm not even sure if the way I'm trying to do this is ideal - it definitely seems dirty to be importing another Jar just so I can run a second main method in code. So I'd appreciate any pointers on the "right way" to do things as well as how to get these things working.

Comment: Well, you should probably find out how the server is configured, you'll need to set the class path (or something similar) on the server in order to include the other Jar file.

Comment: I control the `java` command that is used to launch Java on the server, so I was just going to add it to `cp`. And maybe that will just work. Maybe my only problem is that I can't figure out how to add it to IntelliJ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're building your project via Maven, you need to add your import .jar file as a dependency to the project you're importing the .jar from

If your other project (the .jar you want to import) is already being built by Maven, that's super easy to do.  If not, you can install it to your local .m2 repo with mvn install:install-file (see https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html)

After you have the .jar referenced in your pom file IntelliJ will recognize it.

It is also possible to manually add a .jar file as a dependency to your module in IntelliJ.  I'd recommend avoiding that if possible if you're already using Maven.  If you need to, you can go to your project settings, then "Modules", pick your module, and select "Dependencies", then click the plus sign to add a .jar dependency to your module.

[image]

Comment: Nice, that works well - I ran `mvn install:install-file` and also added the dependency to my pom.xml, and now my import statement isn't failing. There's only one problem... as I mentioned the class I'm importing is called Main, and the class I'd like to use it in is also called Main. Now there's a conflict. Do I have to rename the class I'd like to use it in? I guess there probably isn't an "import x as y" functionality because then things would get pretty weird.

Comment: You can have two Mains but they need to be in different packages.

Comment: Try adding a package statement to the Main class in one of your jars

Comment: I think I'm just going to rename the Main class in my main program. But just to help me understand what happened here, why did installing to my Maven repository (and adding it to the pom.xml) help here? Is it because IntelliJ parses the pom.xml, gets the dependencies, and adds their location in its Maven repository to the classpath for the Java it uses when parsing source files (I think it has its own Maven repository although I'm not positive)?

Comment: That's absolutely correct.  IntelliJ will build its project file from your pom.xml, which will pull the dependencies into your module dependencies (screenshot above).  That's why I don't recommend mixing the two approaches.  Furthermore, if you add the dependency to intellij and not your pom, you won't be able to build the project with just maven anymore.  I've also seen where sometimes IntelliJ will refresh the project from the pom and you'll have to go back and manually add your dependency there again.  You will generally have one maven repository and it's in your user home directory / .m2

Comment: Also, adding a project dependency directly to the IDE's project file will prevent you from being able to do CI builds on a server like Jenkins or VSTS.  Just add the dependencies to your pom and let your IDE figure out how to build its own project file.