# installing a jar to the maven repository on heroku

Tags: java, maven, heroku

I have a .jar that isn't available in Maven Central or any of the other locations that I guess Maven pulls from by default. For my local setup I installed it to my local Maven repository and it worked fine afterwards (discussed in [import another jar's program into my jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49308681/import-another-jars-program-into-my-jar)) - meaning that my import statements in IntelliJ work fine now.

But now I need to deploy my application to Heroku. So I'm sort of stuck: If I keep everything as-is, the Heroku build will fail with `Could not find artifact com.my.company:MyJar:jar:1.0`. But I need the jar in my app one way or the other so I don't think getting rid of the dependency is the way to go.

I'm not really sure where to go from here. I can make the .jar available directly in the files I push to Heroku, but I guess I would need a way to specify something in the pom.xml like "treat the following directory like a repository." But I'm not sure if that's the right way.

Answer (score 0):

This type of JAR file is called an unmanaged dependency. Heroku has [a guide for vendoring JARs like this in your Git repo](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/local-maven-dependencies).

In short, you run a command like:

```
$ mvn deploy:deploy-file -Durl=file:///path/to/yourproject/repo/ -Dfile=mylib-1.0.jar -DgroupId=com.example -DartifactId=mylib -Dpackaging=jar -Dversion=1.0
```

And set the filesystem as a repository in your `pom.xml` like this:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>project.local</id>
        <name>project</name>
        <url>file:${project.basedir}/repo</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

The [Heroku guide to unmanaged dependencies](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/local-maven-dependencies) has more detail.